Access files from other partition
I have a linux/windows dual boot PC. Somehow, the SSD got corrupted and I can't boot on both OS anymore. I installed linux mint in the Windows partition and able to do so. Using this newly installed Linux OS, I am able to navigate to the old linux partition and see the files in the documents and downloads folders but when I try to open them or copy them to the new partition, I am getting an input/output error.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)  Neither Linux Mint or Windows are Ubuntu OSes

I'd advise you to actually take NOTE of what the actual error message is, and evaluate it knowing what exactly you were doing (what you're running etc), as it maybe clue as to hardware problems, and not just a software/metadate/config issue... You're off-topic here, but when you take it to a site appropriate for your chosen OS, don't forget to provide specifics (inc. what Linux Mint, what release etc, as Linux Mint have a product that is Ubuntu based, and another that is Debian based)
